# cakePHP: extract file name without file path from tmp_name

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

In my cakePHP Model i'm trying to use a custom validator to move file to new location an check its success.
the custom method is:

```
    //custom method to check image
public function processCoverUpload($check = array()) {
    if (!is_uploaded_file($check['issue_cover']['tmp_name'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($check['issue_cover']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $check['issue_cover']['tmp_name'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->data[$this->alias]['issue_cover'] = 'uploads' . DS . $check['issue_cove']['tmp_name'];
    return TRUE;
}
```

however `$check['issue_cove']['tmp_name']` returns file name **including its path**.
This will lead to wrong path string in move_uploaded_file. So how can i have only file name out of 'tmp_name'?

### sample

$check['issue_cove']['tmp_name'] is `F:\xampp\tmp\phpF765.tmp` but i want `phpF765.tmp` only.

Comment: No offense, but that's PHP 101, and has already been discussed a million times all over the net:  **http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-375**. On a side note, your validation rules should _only_ validate, moving/storing data is _not_ their concern, that's what should happen in the saving stage!

Comment: Thanks for notice however this sample is brought from [Lynda Coure](http://www.lynda.com/CakePHP-tutorials/Up-Running-CakePHP/126123-2.html)!

Comment: Does't really matter, does it?

Comment: I mean it was a sample tutorial and it was intended to learn how to use custom Validators and it was part of controls done in model to avoid saving model and unset it if any failures happened during file processing.

Comment: please check out uploadError validation rule inside cake php [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way - probably nicer ways though :-)

```
$fname = end(explode('\\',$check['issue_cover']['tmp_name']));
```

$fname should now have the string you want.

ps assumed it should be issue_cover and not issue_cove so change if my assumption was incorrect!

Comment: Now what will happen when this code is being used on a system that uses forward slashes as directory separators (like pretty much any non-windows based OS)? Exactly, it will fail. @l0ckm4 you should have a read on **http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-375** too.

Comment: Rather than provide negative comments with no solution by all means provide a better answer along with the negative comment.  That way we can all learn :-)

Comment: The solution is in the link I've provided, the docs clearly show how it should be done. So how about reading it and updating your answer instead of relying on me (or anyone else) to repeat what has already been explained over and over again? SO is not the place where people do the research for you, that's what _you_ should do before asking or answering questions. Again, no offense.

Comment: Shouting RTFM doesn't really help too much either in my opinion.  The OP obviously has fairly limited PHP knowledge.  By all means refer to the correct page but answer the question as well - which if I am not mistaken was how to get the basename from the full path. - of course basename($path) would have been a better answer to the actual question but you took time out of your day to respond negatively which begs the question why not simply take the same time and be helpful?

Comment: You can use `DS` instead of `'\\'` for slashes, as cake will have DS be the directory separator of the OS

Comment: And @ndm, you should add a solution for fixing the problem you described in this answer, or if you don't like it, add your own answer. But don't discredit other answers just for not reading the manual :)

Comment: I don't want to discredit anyone, and of course I could add my own answer, but what's wrong with encouraging people to help themselves? I don't see the need to always spoon-feed people from a silver platter, just hand them the spoon, otherwise they'll never learn how to eat on their own. @Eagle